# Is there a way to blur compound path in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'd like to blur the edges of holes created by mouse clicks. [This is my example.](https://replit.com/@HaoyueYang/Function-Test?v=1) Now I've used g.js to create differences of two shapes (circles and a rectangle), and then I'd like to blur the edges of these holes on the rectangle. I've tried `fliter(BLUR)`, but the effect was not ideal because it will blur both the holes and the maps under it. I just want to blur the rectangle with holes. Is there any way to do that?

```js
var e2 = [];
var light = [];
var img;
var pg;
var pgPos = [];

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("https://2328a0b8-e236-4076-9848-a3275ab1c3e3.id.repl.co/map%20test.jpg");
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  background(100, 100, 100);
  pg = createGraphics(600, 600);
  
}


function mouseClicked() {

  push();
  let e = g.ellipse({ x: mouseX, y: mouseY }, 100, 100);
  e2.push(e);
  pop();

  light.push(createVector(mouseX, mouseY));
  pgPos.push(createVector(mouseX, mouseY));

}


function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);

  push();
  var e1 = g.rect({ x: width / 2, y: height / 2 }, width, height);
  let pathD = g.compound(e1, e2, 'difference');
  pathD.fill = "rgb(30, 30, 30)";
  pathD.draw(drawingContext);
  pop();


  for (i = 0; i < light.length; i++) {
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 255, 102);
    circle(light[i].x, light[i].y, 30);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nodebox/g.js/master/dist/g.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: FYI, it is preferable to include source code in the question when asking on StackOverflow. I've updated your question to include a runnable snippet of your code from Replit.com

Answer (score 0):

The p5.js `filter()` function seems to apply to the current content of the canvas (and is also very slow). However you can use the native [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) property to achieve the effect you want:

```
drawingContext.filter = 'blur(20px)';
// draw things you want to be blurred
drawingContext.filter = 'none';
```

```js
var e2 = [];
var light = [];
var img;
var pg;
var pgPos = [];

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("https://2328a0b8-e236-4076-9848-a3275ab1c3e3.id.repl.co/map%20test.jpg");
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  background(100, 100, 100);
  pg = createGraphics(600, 600);
  
}


function mouseClicked() {

  push();
  let e = g.ellipse({ x: mouseX, y: mouseY }, 100, 100);
  e2.push(e);
  pop();

  light.push(createVector(mouseX, mouseY));
  pgPos.push(createVector(mouseX, mouseY));

}


function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);

  push();
  drawingContext.filter = 'blur(20px)';
  var e1 = g.rect({ x: width / 2, y: height / 2 }, width, height);
  let pathD = g.compound(e1, e2, 'difference');
  pathD.fill = "rgb(30, 30, 30)";
  pathD.draw(drawingContext);
  drawingContext.filter = 'none';
  pop();

  for (i = 0; i < light.length; i++) {
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 255, 102);
    circle(light[i].x, light[i].y, 30);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nodebox/g.js/master/dist/g.min.js"></script>
```